# Make args: is there a variable that contains all of them?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In `make`, I can define a file as follows:

```
.PHONY: echo-foo

echo-foo:
    echo ${foo}
```

Usage:

```
make echo-foo foo=foo
```

Now suppose I would like to do the following:

```
make echo-vars foo=foo bar=bar
```

And I start by writing:

```
echo-vars:
   echo ${???}
```

Is there a variable automatically defined which will output:

```
// either
foo=foo bar=bar

// or 
foo bar
```

---

In other words: is there a `MAKEARGS` or some variable along those lines defined as part of the `make` env?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [special variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-MAKEOVERRIDES) just for that:

```
echo-vars:
    echo ${MAKEOVERRIDES}
```

Comment: Knew it!  `make` is awesome

Answer (score 1):

[.VARIABLES](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#Special-Variables) is somewhat close.

This prints only command-line variables:

```
test:
    echo "$(foreach VAR_NAME,$(.VARIABLES),\
        $(if $(filter command line,$(origin $(VAR_NAME))),$(VAR_NAME)))"
```

- `$(filter command line,$(origin VAR_NAME))` equals to `"command line"` if it's the value of `$(origin VAR_NAME)`, and is empty otherwise. `$(filter <needle>,<haystack>)` is a `make`'s boolean test for `"<needle> is in or equals to <haystack> and is not empty"`.
- `$(if <condition>,<value>)` returns `<value>` if `<condition>` is nonempty, otherwise an empty string.
- `$(foreach VAR_NAME,SET,EXPRESSION)` returns a joined result of `EXPRESSION` applied to each element of a (space-separated) `SET`, where `VAR_NAME` is substituted with each element of the `SET`.

Add `$(strip)` to get rid of excess spaces.

Comment: And great explanation.  Both answers are great!